# Counting comments with one level of nesting

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I've got a comment system in which users can comment on posts, and then users can reply to those top-level comments. That's the extend of the nesting: users cannot reply to replies.

Top-level comments and replies live in the same table. They're almost identical. Top-level comments have a `post_id`, and replies have a `parent_id`. I use a constraint on the table to ensure that exactly one of these columns has a value for each row.

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    post_id integer,
    author_id integer NOT NULL,
    body text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    parent_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT must_have_media_item_xor_parent CHECK ((((media_item_id IS NULL) AND (parent_id IS NOT NULL)) OR ((media_item_id IS NOT NULL) AND (parent_id IS NULL))))
);
```

Now I'd like to count all of the comments, including replies, on a particular post. The query

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM comments
WHERE comments.post_id = 123
```

tells me how many top-level comments post #123 has. The query

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM comments
 JOIN comments AS replies ON replies.parent_id = comments.id
WHERE comments.post_id = 123
```

tells me how many replies there are. I could do both and add them together, but that sounds heavy, and hopefully unnecessary.

One solution, which would avoid the self join from the second query, would be to set the `post_id` on replies as well, denormalizing the value. Then the first query would count all of them. If I do that, I'd really like to have some sort of consistency check in the database to make sure I have it right.

Is there a way to get Postgres to constrain the value of `post_id` to that of its parent when `parent_id` is set? Normal constraints appear to only be able to look at a single row.

Or, is there another good way to count all the comments in one fell swoop?

Comment: I posted untested reply. If you provide sample data I will create `SQL Fiddle`, so you we can test it.

Comment: Questions like this *need*  to provide relevant table definitions (like you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Also, your version of Postgres. And some sample data for a test case would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! (Credit to PM 77-1 for inspiration from his answer.)

I was thinking about the joining backwards. Rather than come down from the root, I needed to walk back from the leaves.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN comments AS parents ON comments.parent_id = parents.id
WHERE comments.post_id = 123 OR parents.post_id = 123
```

Translation: Get all comments, both top-level and replies. For replies, get the info on their parents too. Now filter that result to the comments which are directly on this post *or* which are in reply to a parent that's on this post.

Notice that in my original attempt in the question, my query didn't actually take advantage of the fact that the top-level comments and the replies are in the same table. This one does. It selects the top-level comments and the replies on the same side of the join (the left), and uses the right side of the join only to get more information to filter the replies.

(This also means that I may be able to get ActiveRecord to use this query as an association, which would be nifty.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PostgreSQL supports [`COUNT DISTINCT`](http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-count-function.php)

You may want to try something like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(comments.post_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT replies.post_id)) As Total_Count 
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN comments AS replies ON replies.parent_id = comments.id
WHERE comments.post_id = 123
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` to account for posts with no replies.